# WindowManager$BadTokenException with misspelled words in EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-input-method, android-windowmanager

I have a problem with `EditText` of the inputType `text`, when defining an `EditText` like the following way:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/text_name"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:text="some txt"
    .
    .
    ./>
```

here the `inputType` is `text`, and the text value is `"some txt"` which contains a misspelled word which is **"txt"**. And this EditText is contained in a layout which is displayed as a pop-up window.

Now when some `Button` clicked in the `Activity` and this layout is poped-up, the word **txt** is underlined as a wrong word, and when focusing in any other word in the `EditText` the keyboard appearing normally and nothing wrong happening, but when focusing in the misspelled word **txt** the app crashes with the following exception:

```
11-09 16:50:02.126: W/dalvikvm(5205): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40ffc9a8)
11-09 16:50:02.127: W/System.err(5205): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@41656d18 is not valid; is your activity running?
11-09 16:50:02.127: W/System.err(5205):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:646)
11-09 16:50:02.127: W/System.err(5205):     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:248)
11-09 16:50:02.127: W/System.err(5205):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
11-09 16:50:02.127: W/System.err(5205):     at android.widget.PopupWindow.invokePopup(PopupWindow.java:993)
11-09 16:50:02.127: W/System.err(5205):     at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAtLocation(PopupWindow.java:847)
11-09 16:50:02.128: W/System.err(5205):     at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAtLocation(PopupWindow.java:811)
11-09 16:50:02.128: W/System.err(5205):     at android.widget.Editor$PinnedPopupWindow.updatePosition(Editor.java:2207)
11-09 16:50:02.128: W/System.err(5205):     at android.widget.Editor$PinnedPopupWindow.show(Editor.java:2164)
11-09 16:50:02.128: W/System.err(5205):     at android.widget.Editor$SuggestionsPopupWindow.show(Editor.java:2406)
11-09 16:50:02.128: W/System.err(5205):     at android.widget.Editor.showSuggestions(Editor.java:1700)
11-09 16:50:02.128: W/System.err(5205):     at android.widget.Editor$1.run(Editor.java:1599)
11-09 16:50:02.128: W/System.err(5205):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
11-09 16:50:02.129: W/System.err(5205):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-09 16:50:02.129: W/System.err(5205):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
11-09 16:50:02.129: W/System.err(5205):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
11-09 16:50:02.129: W/System.err(5205):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-09 16:50:02.130: W/System.err(5205):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-09 16:50:02.133: W/System.err(5205):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
11-09 16:50:02.134: W/System.err(5205):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
11-09 16:50:02.134: W/System.err(5205):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And to fix this bug I have to change the `inputType` in the `EditText` to `textNoSuggestions`.

So, why this problem is happen? and how to use `inputType` as `text` and deal with the misspelled words without any problems?

---

And this is how I deal with it programmatically:

```
private static PopupWindow pw;
private View layout;
private static ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.popup_container);

private void initiate_popup(){
    layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup,
            vg);
    pw = new PopupWindow(layout, 500,
            450, true);
    pw.setOutsideTouchable(true);
    pw.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(
            android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
    pw.setTouchInterceptor(on_outside_touch);
    pw.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss() {
            hideKeyboard();
        }
    });

    // display the popup in the center
    pw.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

    String name = "some txt";

    // Declaring EditText
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    final EditText text_name = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.text_name);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(text_name.getWindowToken(), 0);
    text_name.setText(name);
}

// hide Keyboard method
public void hideKeyboard() {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) ctx
            .getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    if (imm.isActive()) {
        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0); // hide
    } else {
        ctx.getWindow()
                .setSoftInputMode(
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by changing the `inputType` of the text, instead of `text` I changed it to `textNoSuggestions` which will not even look if the entered word is correct or not, and hence the app will not crash when focusing it.

So, the text will defined as:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/text_name"
    android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
    android:text="some txt"
    .
    .
    ./>
```